# Restricting web requests to a particular domain or subfolder

Tags: web-server, domain, request, directory

Is it possible to setup a website so that it only accepts requests from one particular domain / subfolder?

If so, how is this done?

Comment: -1 for poor question title. I'll vote back up if you edit the title so that it is more descriptive and therefore might match searches for this topic.

Comment: The question itself isn't so hot. How do you accept a request from a subfolder?

Comment: Which platform and technology are you using?

Answer (score 0):

Yes.  You would just look at the CGI variable REMOTE_ADDR.  Or, are you talking about the [Referer](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Referer)?  If you mean the latter, keep in mind it can be forged.

Comment: I think REMOTE_ADDR can be forged too, can't it?

Comment: No.  An HTTP GET requires an fully open TCP/IP connection, which requires two-way communication.

Answer (score 0):

If you are using apache you could setup access using .htaccess files in the folder you want to restrict.   Or you could modify the .conf files and set up restrictions there.